# Can 100 bicycles be made from the materials used to build one car?

Tags: social-media, bicycles, vehicle

I found this [tweet from Greenpeace Colombia](https://twitter.com/GreenpeaceColom/status/717841876716376064) which says:

*(In Spanish):*

> *Con los materiales usados para hacer un auto se hacen 100 bicicletas.*

*(Translated):*

> *The materials used to build one car could make 100 bicycles*

*Screenshot of the original tweet:*

[image: Tweet from Greenpeace Colombia]

Is that assertion/claim accurate?

Comment: This seems a little vague. They could be including the materials used in the making of the car that don't actually end up a part of the final product.

Comment: Only if you just consider mass - a bike might weigh 10 kg, a car 1000 kg.  But you would likely use different materials.

Comment: I don't have the calculations to prove it, but I'd guess 4 car tyres wouldn't make 200 bike tyres even if you took rubber for seals and other sources in the car

Comment: The claim is kind of meaningless: a car can weigh 800 kgs - 2,400 kgs.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Bikes probably vary about as much in weight.  Consider carbon fiber & titanium racing bike vs heavy retro-style cruiser.

Comment: Even if it is true a 100 bikes still won't get me to work on time.

Comment: @jamesqf: Yes, making it even more vague. (I almost made that point too, but I wanted to be able to back up what I said with references, and I didn't have them for bikes.)

Comment: @fredsbend my commute through the city takes twice as long by car as it does by bike

Answer (score 4):

This is obviously not true. You have to look at the different materials cars or bicycles are made from because that statement doesn't restrict itself to a specific material.

This would require the rubber of 200 bicycle tires to be at most the amount of rubber used to make a car. Most of that rubber is found in the tires of which a car has 5 (let's give it a spare tire). Therefore you needed to be able to make about 40 bicycle tires from the rubber used to make a since car tire – which obviously by looking at the mass alone doesn't work out.

---

Since someone actually disputes this, here are some sources.

You can find [here](http://www.ecy.wa.gov/programs/swfa/tires/) that a car tire has a mass of 22 pounds (9.98 kg). The page also states how a car tire is composed. It's 41% rubber which means that one car tire has 4.09 kg rubber. Therefore, each bicycle tire had to have 102 g of rubber or less. You can take from [this page](http://weightweenies.starbike.com/listings/components.php?type=innertubes) that the inner tubes alone have about that mass and [the shells even add about twice that 102 g](http://weightweenies.starbike.com/listings/components.php%3Ftype=roadtyres) to the total mass of the rubber part of a bicycle tire.

You can find out from the first link that there isn't much other than rubber and carbon to the rubber part of a tire. But for the numbers to match up, more than two thirds of the rubber parts stated above had to be something different than rubber.

Comment: What are bike tires made of?  How much rubber is in a car?  What about waste materials?  What about other components (this could easily be 'roughly true' even if tires are out by a bit).  If you're going to do original research, you're going to have to try a lot harder than that.